# Will SQL Server Express work with a database made in regular SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-express

I was wondering if we could backup the database that we currently host on regular SQL Server, and put it onto our clients computer when we setup SQL Server Express for them.

Is this possible?
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Yes providing the database engine version number is the same or a previous version: sql server  <= sql express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to restore a database backup from the Standard edition to the Express edition. It's not possible to restore a SQL Server 2008 to a SQL Server 2005 version, though.

However, there a some minor differences between versions. I've noticed an issue in SQL Server Express 2005 when calling .NET SQL CLR functions across databases, so your mileage may vary. I haven't been able to find a good overview of the exact differences between the various SQL Server editions.

It's always best to keep the development platform as close as possible to the release platform. I can only recommend that you use the Express edition of SQL Server for development as well; and re-test your application.

Comment: @JNK: 4 GB up to and including 2008, 10 GB for 2008 R2 (and most likely 2011/Denali)